# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Sys' is undefined (in mvc3 c# razor)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

**in cshtml**

`<form action="/Sp/EditSp" method="post" onclick="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleClick(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event));" onsubmit="Sys.Mvc.AsyncForm.handleSubmit(this, new Sys.UI.DomEvent(event), { insertionMode: Sys.Mvc.InsertionMode.replace, httpMethod: &#39;POST&#39;, updateTargetId: &#39;divDisplay&#39;, onSuccess: Function.createDelegate(this, deactivateAList) });"><input type="hidden" id="requestSequence" name="requestSequence" value="24" />`

**javascript:**

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deactivateAList() {
    document.getElementById("AList").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

`

Kindly, tell me how to resolve this error.

Comment: Where did all that javascript in your cshtml come from? What is it for? You're probably just missing some necessary js files

Comment: In fact, the javascript function is present in xyz.js file. for the sake of readers understanding, I have put it here. I have also included the xyz.js into my cshtml. but that dint resolve the issue

Comment: Hi @gideon, What all can be the causes for this error?

Comment: I have added `<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" />` but still i can face the error.

Answer (score 6):

I have added :

`<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />`

in **Web.Config**

Comment: It's an old question but I just spent 2h trying to figure out wth is wrong... thanks this solved my issue!